# Script which choose latest file and sends it via FTP

Tags: powershell, ftp

I want this script to choose the latest file from a folder and then send it via ftp to the server.

I think it is choosing the file late because there is a new file on the FTP after running it. However it crashes constantly showing

```
uploading .....
uploading .....
uploading .....
```

```psh
$Dir="C:/log1"    
$ftp = "ftpftpftp" 
$user = "useruseruser" 
$pass = "passpasspass"  
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  
 for($latest){ 
    "Uploading $latest..." 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$latest.Name) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $latest.FullName) 
 }
```

Comment: You have a loop in there `for($latest)`. What happens when you remove that loop? The following is an infinite printing loop: `for(1){"Hello? Is it me you are looking for?"}` Remove the infinite loop you have created.

Comment: Agree with Matt, change for($latest) to if($latest) if you want to check that $latest variable was populated before calling the upload.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using the wrong code block by accident. Currently you have created an infinite loop as you have no condition to how the `for` will exit.

A simple example of such a loop would be

```
for(){"Hello? Is it me you are looking for?"}
```

It should be structured like this

```
for (initialization; condition; repeat){code block}
```

an example would be

```
for($index =1; $index -lt 6;$index++){$index}
```

---

There is no need for that code block at all *as long as `$Dir` is not empty*. What you can do for a little error prevention is `if($latest){}` which will only work if `$latest` contains a file (in this code structure).

```
if($latest){ 
    "Uploading $latest..." 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$latest.Name) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $latest.FullName) 
}
```

Your sample output does not have a file name in it so I suspect your `$dir` contains no files?